# how to unwrap union value in list in f#

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

You know that to unwrap a value of a single union type you have to do this:

```
type Foo = Foo of int*string

let processFoo foo =
    let (Foo (t1,t2)) = foo
    printfn "%A %A" t1 t2
```

but my question is: if there a way to do that for lists ?:

```
let processFooList (foolist:Foo list )  =
    let ??? = foolist // how to get a int*string list
    ...
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use a function combined with `List.map` like so

```
let processFooList (foolist:Foo list )  = foolist |> List.map (function |Foo(t1,t2)->t1,t2)
```

Comment: so there is no predefined active pattern to do this

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined active pattern for converting the list from `Foo` to `int * string`, but you could combine the Named Pattern [§7.2](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818906) (deconstruct single case union) with the projection into your own single case Active Pattern [§7.2.3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818909).

```
let asTuple (Foo(t1, t2)) = t1, t2      // extract tuple from single Foo
let (|FooList|) =  List.map asTuple     // apply to list
```

Use as function argument:

```
let processFooList (FooList fooList) =  // now you can extract tuples from Foo list
    ...                                 // fooList is an (int * string) list
```

Use in let-binding:

```
let (FooList fooList) = 
    [ Foo(1, "a"); Foo(2, "b") ]
printfn "%A" fooList                    // prints [(1, "a"); (2, "b")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Distilling/summarising/restating/reposting the other two answers, your cited line:

```
let ??? = foolist // how to get a int*string list
```

Can become:

```
let ``???`` = foolist |> List.map (function |Foo(x,y) -> x,y)
```

If you're writing a transformation, you can do the matching in the params having defined an Active Pattern using either of the following:

```
let (|FooList|) = List.map <| fun (Foo(t1, t2)) -> t1,t2
let (|FooList|) = List.map <| function |Foo(t1, t2) -> t1,t2
```

which can then be consumed as follows:

```
let processFooList (fooList:Foo list )  =
    // do something with fooList
```